# Keep ScrollView scroll position for dynamic content

Tags: android, scrollview

What I want to archive can be best explained with an image

[image]

The gray box represents the screen, the blue box is meta information, the white rounded box is a SearchView and the red boxes are items returned from the search.

I got this working so far, but the problem occurs when the user searches for something and the items exceed the screen (1). Afterwards the user scrolls down, so the meta information is outside the screen (2). The user can now still enter a new search query and thus change the items. However, when the new query returns too few items to fill the rest of the screen (3) the ScrollView will "jump" back to the top (not in image, not desired). What I want is a behavior where the SearchView stays put (3). Once in this state the user can scroll back to the top (4). If she does she cannot scroll back though, instead the overscroll indicators will show.

Similar behavior can be seen in the Google+ App. From the start screen go to your profile (tap on your name on the top). You will see three registers ("About me", "Posts", "Photos" *). I have for example no photos in there and the behavior is as described.

**edit** The ScrollView is the root of the View.

**edit** Basic layout structure

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:overScrollMode="always"
  android:fillViewport="true">

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <View /> <!-- Meta info -->
      <SearchView />
      <View /> <!-- Item representing search result -->
      <View /> <!-- Item representing search result -->
      <View /> <!-- Item representing search result -->
      <View /> <!-- Item representing search result -->
      <View /> <!-- Item representing search result -->
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*) Assumed translation from the German App.

Comment: Since I am not familiar with typically how this is done, perhaps you can provide some snippets of which classes are being used to achieve this scroll behavior that you have working so far. Pondering the process and trying to find an approach.

Comment: Have you tried using scrollTo() to shift the ScrollView back down? Not sure it is what you should use but it may help.

Comment: It's just a plain ScrollView around everything else. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Yes I tried scrollTo, it's not working. The problem is that the ScrollView shrinks to the content. Which just sparked the idea to use fillViewport together with scroll to.

Comment: @Mene There is built-in behavior for achieving (2) where you keep the search component at the top?  Or you have some code managing and keeping it offscreen there while keeping the search bar at the top?

Comment: The SeachView is not kept at the top. It's only a scenario where the user happend to have scrolled to this position. Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: In the case your scroll view automatically shrinks,you could also try to alignParentBottom for your scroll view.That way you can prevent it from shrinking right?

Comment: Sounds good, but alignParentBottom doesn't work. Just tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there seems to be no standard solution in the android sdk, nor any public code doing this I tinkered my own solution. This is my working solution:

I wrapped the search results in a LinearLayout and used minimumHeight to archive the desired behavior. This way I don't need to fiddle with measurements when items are added to the list.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/scroll_placeholder"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
  <View /> <!-- result -->
  <View /> <!-- result -->
  <View /> <!-- result -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Search results are retrieved asynchronous so I clear the List and start a search indicator when a new search is triggered. At this point I also set the minimum height to the size of the visible rect of the `itemList`. Note that the `itemList` is not a `ScrollView` as otherwise there would be a ScrollView within a ScrollView which is problematic. It's basically a LinearLayout containing the results.

```
int scrollY = rootScrollView.getScrollY();
if (scrollY > 0) {
    final Rect visibleListViewRect = new Rect();
    placeholder.getGlobalVisibleRect(visibleListViewRect);
    placeholder.setMinimumHeight(visibleListViewRect.height());
} else {
    placeholder.setMinimumHeight(0);
}
```

This will give the behavior as seen in image 3) of the question.

To disable scrolling back down once the user has scrolled up (image 4) I added a ScrollChangedListener:

```
placeholder.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        int scrollY = placeholder.getScrollY();
        if (scrollY > 0) {
            final Rect visibleListViewRect = new Rect();
            placeholder.getGlobalVisibleRect(visibleListViewRect);
            placeholder.setMinimumHeight(visibleListViewRect.height());
        } else {
            placeholder.setMinimumHeight(0);
        }
    }
});
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

since you have not mentioned any code.I can just refer you to possible solutions.I had faced a similar problem.The issue you are facing is due to focus of the child layouts.The most effective solution is to control this focus.

Try using

```
ScrollView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
```

and also when your searchBox is being used,you can programmatically do

```
searchBox.requestFocus()
```

for more control you can also try MotionListener.If you can also add the code I could be more specific.
And dont forget to check the scroll view methods http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

FYI playing with focus will give you a lot of interesting scenarios and animations/motions too :)

Comment: I added an outline of my layout. But honestly I cannot see how this has anything to do with the focus.

Comment: Ok.. What if you added another  layout below your linearlayout(list views).. To fill the remaining part of the  scroll view layout.

Comment: Yeah, that is the solution I am implementing now. Was also the first way to solve it that came to my mind, but it's actually pretty complicated if you keep image 4) in mind. I was hoping for something more straight forward, especially since it's done in Google+.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'll have time to come back to this later and update with additional details of how I think I would tackle this.  But as for now I'll just post something that I have time for.

I believe this would be done with a scrollview below and just a view above.  One over the meta-data and the searchview and another over the elements you want to scroll over in a simulated list.

A check would have to be performed as you scroll over the simulated list below.  Decrease the size of the view above by actions from the scrollview below based on listeners on the scrollview; to the limit of the size of the searchview.  Then when the condition is met that the scrollview below has reached the end, enlarge the upper view to fill the space.